# Some algebra in Leibniz's letters (Original clue for determinants form)

Tags: linear-algebra

In *Muir, Thomas. The theory of determinants in the historical order of development. Vol. 1. Macmillan and Company, limited, 1906.*, it is shown that Leibniz pioneered the idea of using numbers to represent variables in linear equations instead of letters. I found the following system of equations:

$$10 + 11x + 12y = 0 \quad(1)$$
$$20 + 21x + 22y = 0 \quad(2)$$
$$30 + 31x + 32y = 0 \quad(3)$$

where 10 / 11 / 12 etc. are variables not face values.

It is followed that,

$$10*22+11*22x\\-12*20-12*21x = 0 \quad(4)$$

$$10*32+11*32x\\-12*30-12*31x = 0 \quad(5)$$

(they are slightly different from the footnote of Muir)

which are trivial by eliminating $y$. (4) follows (1) and (2) ; (5) follows (1) and (3).

Finally, it is concluded that by eliminating $x$,

$$
10*21*32 \quad 10*22*31\\
+11*22*30 = + 11*20*32\\
+12*20*31 \quad +12*21*30
$$

Which has the same form as `Leibniz formula for determinants` in the `n=3` case.

I still don't understand how it made a jump to the last equation. How do you use (4) and (5) to do that?

[a caption of the text is provided here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9bcP.png)

I did google translate the text so can add them if needed.

Comment: Just because they used broken notation doesn’t mean we should. It will be easier to see if you write $a_{11}$ instead of $11,$ etc.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thanks for the advice, but I have solved the problem by myself. Will leave the format as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the solution was not that difficult, I just lacked the audacity to execute.

Forgive me for using their "old" notation, following (4) and (5):

$$\frac{10*22 - 12*20}{12*21 - 11*22} = \frac{10*32 - 12*30}{12*31 - 11*32}$$

thus

$$10*22*12*31 - 12*20*12*31 - 10*22*11*32 + 12*20*11*32 \\ = \\ 10*32*12*21 - 12*30*12*21 - 10*32*11*22 + 12*30*11*22$$

the term $10*22*11*32$ is repeated on both sides, which can be removed

dividing $12$ on both sides, we have the result that Leibniz gave,

Comment: Of course, that assumes $12\neq 0.$

Comment: And technically, you can’t divide by those numbers of they are $0.$ The general way to find the requirements for a solution to $$\alpha_1+\beta_1x=0, \alpha_2+\beta_2x=0$$ is to multiply the first by $\beta_2,$ the second by $\beta_1$ and subtract, getting $\alpha_1\beta_2-\alpha_2\beta_1=0.$ Your $(4)$ and $(5)$ givens $\alpha_i,\beta_i,$ and this amounts to the same calculation you did, but without potentially dividing by zero. You’d still require $12\neq 0$ to divide at the end.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, that's a technicality I missed. Thanks a lot.